# Chainlink CCIP Token Transfer error; failure to generate proper Client.EVM2AnyMessage

Tags: chainlink, foundry, ccip

I am trying to follow the Chainlink's [masterclass on CCIP](https://cll-devrel.gitbook.io/chainlink-ccip/ccip-masterclass/exercise-1-transfer-tokens) in transferring a token cross chain but I keep getting roadblocked with this one error,

`Error:  (code: -32000, message: execution reverted, data: None)`

when I call the transfer function in `CCIPTokenSender.sol`. I can call the withdrawToken function, I've funded my contract no problem with foundry. But when it comes to calling the transferTokens function, that above error.

```
function transferTokens(
        uint64 _destinationChainSelector,
        address _receiver,
        address _token,
        uint256 _amount
    ) 
        external
        onlyOwner
        onlyWhitelistedChain(_destinationChainSelector)
        returns (/*bytes32 messageId*/ bool) 
    {
        Client.EVMTokenAmount[]
            memory tokenAmounts = new Client.EVMTokenAmount[](1);
        Client.EVMTokenAmount memory tokenAmount = Client.EVMTokenAmount({
            token: _token,
            amount: _amount
        });
        tokenAmounts[0] = tokenAmount;
        
        // Build the CCIP Message
        Client.EVM2AnyMessage memory message = Client.EVM2AnyMessage({
            receiver: abi.encode(_receiver),
            data: "",
            tokenAmounts: tokenAmounts,
            extraArgs: /*Client._argsToBytes(
                Client.EVMExtraArgsV1({gasLimit: 0, strict:false})
            )*/"",
            feeToken: address(linkToken)
        });
        
        // CCIP Fees Management
        //*********************
        // ERROR BELOW********
        //*********************
        uint256 fees = router.getFee(_destinationChainSelector, message);
        return true;

        /*
       if (fees > linkToken.balanceOf(address(this)))
            revert NotEnoughBalance(linkToken.balanceOf(address(this)), fees);

        linkToken.approve(address(router), fees);
        /*
        // Approve Router to spend CCIP-BnM tokens we send
        IERC20(_token).approve(address(router), _amount);
        
        // Send CCIP Message
        messageId = router.ccipSend(_destinationChainSelector, message); 
        
        emit TokensTransferred(
            messageId,
            _destinationChainSelector,
            _receiver,
            _token,
            _amount,
            address(linkToken),
            fees
        );*/
    }
```

I've downgraded to the below npm packages;

```
    "@chainlink/contracts": "^0.8.0",
    "@chainlink/contracts-ccip": "^0.7.6"
```

I've had to change an Client.sol function parameter from the library since no matter what I did, it did not accept 2 arguments for EVMExtraArgsV1. Initially I had zero, then I just commented it out and left with "". None of them worked.

```
        Client.EVM2AnyMessage memory message = Client.EVM2AnyMessage({
            receiver: abi.encode(_receiver),
            data: "",
            tokenAmounts: tokenAmounts,
            extraArgs: /*Client._argsToBytes(
                Client.EVMExtraArgsV1({gasLimit: 0, strict:false})
            )*/"",
            feeToken: address(linkToken)
        });
```

And my foundry command to run this function on command line

`cast send $TEST_ADDRESS --rpc-url $DEPLOYER_CHAIN --private-key=$PRIVATE_KEY "transferTokens(uint64,address,address,uint256)" 16015286601757825753 $DEPLOYER $CCIP_BnM_ADDRESS 100`

where on the

Test address was the contract I deployed on Avalanche Fuji (also tried Mumbai), and I sent it to my own address (Deployer) on Sepolia (the number starting with 160). I don't know what else to do. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: HI there there were new (breaking) changes in CCIP after that masterclass repo was published. Software evolves! :) 
https://docs.chain.link/ccip/release-notes
As part of these there are new router addresses, etc -- refer the link above. And you dont need "strict:false" in  Client.EVMExtraArgsV1 etc.

Hope this helps!